# I'm unsure as to why i'm seeing undefined while using react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So i'm trying to integrate redux into my react code and i'm getting a problem where the array i'm trying to access is undefined.  It is the console.log statement in the first block of code.  I'm just trying to read data from the redux store.  I've been trying to figure out why this is a problem as my object types should be fine and it should be connected correctly.  I'm just not sure at this point.

InterestList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class InterestList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className = 'container'>
                {console.log(this.props.skillList)}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{skillList: state.skillList}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InterestList)
```

Reducer for parent component

```
import {ADD_INTEREST} from "./Constant";
const initialState = {
    skillList: [{skillName: '', skillValue: '', interestValue: ''}]
}
export function interestCard(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_INTEREST:
            return [...state, action.payload]
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Action for parent component

```
import {ADD_INTEREST} from './Constant'

export const addInterest = interest => ({
    type: ADD_INTEREST,
    payload: interest
})
```

Combine Reducers

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {interestCard} from "./InterestCardReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    interestCard,
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Did you defined `combineReducers` method?

Comment: Yes. I added it to the existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this :

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    interestCard,
})
```

you should access the state like this : `state.interestCard.skillList` and not this way `state.skillList`.

Something else that's wrong is that inside the reducer `interestCard`, your initial state suggests that the state is an object, not an array ! so this `return [...state, action.payload]` will throw an error.

And Last thing :

```
   <div className = 'container'>
        {console.log(this.props.skillList)}
    </div>
```

This won't work, because `console.log` is not evaluated to a String or to a React element or to a list of these 2.